# what should be column type for embedded type field, while writing changelog in liquibase

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

```
@Entity
public class A{
  private String aa;
  @Embedded
  private Addreess bb;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address{
  private String dd;
}
```

while writing the changelog below are some of the syntaxes that I have already tried

```
              - column:
                  name: address
                  type: embedded  // not working
  also
              - column:
                  name: address
                  type: OTHER  //not working

also    
              - column:
                  name: address
                  type: Address  //not working
```

i am new liquibase i am using in spring java

Comment: it is reolved, we have to define each individual column of embedded type